# Trying to parse through SQL data to make an easier-to-handle associative array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, object, associative-array

I'm using Wordpress for this, but it is not a Wordpress-centric issue, so I am asking here.

You can see a snippet of my code here: http://pastebin.com/Cbc8wKvB

```
<?php

function getFormIds() 
{
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "
                        SELECT a.id
                        FROM wp_rg_lead a
                        WHERE a.form_id = 10 AND a.payment_status = 'Approved'
        ";

        $query = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        if($query)
                return $query;

        return false;
}

function getFormInfo($form_id) 
{
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "
                        SELECT *
                        FROM wp_rg_lead_detail
                        WHERE lead_id = $form_id
                        ";

        $query = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        if($query)
                return $query;

        return false;
}


$credit_card_form_ids = getFormIds();

if ( $credit_card_form_ids ) {
        $entries = array();

        foreach( $credit_card_form_ids as $entry) {
                $single_entry = getFormInfo($entry->id);

                if ( $single_entry ) {

                        $entry_array = array();
                        $full_array = array();

                        foreach( $single_entry as $entry ) {
                                $curr_array = array( $entry->field_number => strip_tags($entry->value));
                                $entry_array[$entry->field_number] = strip_tags($entry->value);
                                array_push($full_array, $entry_array);
                        }
                }
        }
        #var_dump('full_array', $full_array);
}
```

Basically I'm running a DB query to grab all entry ID's that match a certain criterion. This returns an array of objects of single values. I then pass this array through a `foreach()` and try to extract/combine data to make it easier to work with.

Here is a `print_r()` of a `$single_entry` from the code above: http://pastebin.com/RZmfD2EU

single entry:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1983
            [lead_id] => 86
            [form_id] => 10
            [field_number] => 34
            [value] => 695
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1982
            [lead_id] => 86
            [form_id] => 10
            [field_number] => 39
            [value] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1981
            [lead_id] => 86
            [form_id] => 10
            [field_number] => 40.1
            [value] => Yes
        )
    ... etc etc.
```

With the code I provided, the final array seems to collapse somehow -- meaning I lose entries somewhere along the way.

Ideally I'd love the data to associate `id`'s to their `key` => `value` pairs. Namely:

```
 [id] => [lead_id]
 [field_number#] => [field_number_value]
```

For a actual representation of the first few lines of data provided:

```
Array (
    [0] =>
        (
            [id] => 86
            [34] => 695
            [39] => 0
            [40.1] => Yes
            ...etc
        )
)
```

Is there a better way to loop through and associate data than what I'm doing? I'm relatively new/bad at PHP and MySQL and would love some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding it right but if you want to assign values to specified keys…

```
if ( $single_entry ) {

    $entry_array = array();
    $full_array = array();

    foreach( $single_entry as $entry ) {
        $curr_array = array( $entry->field_number => strip_tags($entry->value));
        $entry_array[$entry->field_number] = strip_tags($entry->value);
        $lead_id = $entry['lead_id'];
        $full_array[$lead_id] = $entry_array;
    }
}
```